# Check for Block Ads/Scripts (Browser Addons, Compatibility)

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, add-on

I'm conflicted. you guys decide if this should migrate to SU or not.

I would like to test my site against popular browser ad ons. ATM i have tested against noscript and adblock plus for firefox. What other popular ad ons should i check compatibility with?

By compatibility i mean to work as intent on browsers i support (opera, firefox, chrome, IE 7/8) which include ads. NoScript broke my site and for adblock plus i ask once per week to consider allowing ads. When i see IE6 i notify the user the site is known to be unusable with that browser (The site is script heavy by nature and i wouldnt want to accidentally serve ads to infect users of IE6 with a virus).

Comment: That's certainly a question for SO. It would be an SU question if it said 'What are popular ad blocker add-ons?' or similar. (Not a bad idea to find/start a question over there for that as research.. but you have a greater chance of hitting a developer/designer who has a suite they test against on here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't generally serve ads, so I don't go out of my way to test this stuff, but here are some links that may help you determine *popularity* (though it would be good if someone could give insight as to the practicality of testing such and such).

- [What is the best solution for ad blocking with FireFox and Explorer 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/27043/what-is-the-best-solution-for-ad-blocking-with-firefox-and-explorer-8)
- [Can I use Adblock's database in Opera?](https://superuser.com/questions/1694/can-i-use-adblocks-database-in-opera) (Has link to article on content filtering in Opera...though, sorry Opera users, you're kind of an edge case, and I don't know that the OP can counter this...)
- [Is 'Ad Muncher' the best ad-blocker for IE8?](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=237245)